# How to gain a permission for copy/pasting for system folders?

Tags: command-line, clipboard

I've been using Windows OS before, and it's a bit hard for me copying and pasting to Ubuntu's system folders so. If i drag file or folder into File system folders, I'm getting "permission denied" error.
Is there any way to copy/paste file/folders easily (not by Terminal)?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you press `Alt + F2` to get to the Run Application screen, and then type `gksudo nautilus` it will ask for your password and drop you into a nautilus session where you can drag drop into system folders, however, be very careful since you can destroy your system if you're not careful.